# Proving Big-Oh Notation

Tags: java, big-o

I have been trying to prove how f(n) = log(n^3) is O(logn).
I get what O(logn) complexity means but I can wrap my head around by proving log(n^3) is O(logn)

**If this question has already been asked, please link me to that post. Thanks.

Comment: As an asker, you are responsible for ensuring that the question has not been asked already, not us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mathematical law which states that `log(n^x) = x * log(n)`. Now, the O-Notation simply ignores all constant factors, yielding `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Oh yeah!! that just reminded me that rule.